# NSFetchedResultsController delegate callback for relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, delegates, relationship, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Suppose you have two entities, one is `People`, the other is `Location`. `Location` has an attribute `name`, `People` has a to-one relationship to `Location` named `location`.

Then if you have an `NSFetchedResultsController` like below, you can't get the delegate callback when you change the `Location`s `name`.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"People"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"location.name" 
                                                               ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = 
   [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                       managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"location.name" 
                                                  cacheName:@"Master"];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

I know I can fetch the `Location` entity and then filter it by `name` to solve this problem. But I'm curious about this, does the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate just notify you when something changed in the entity's relationship，not the relationship's attribute.

Can anyone give me some posts about this feature. I search the web and Apple's documentation but can't find a reasonable description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate just notify you when something changed in the entity's relationship，not the relationship's attribute.

Exactly. Because a change in the relationship is a change in the object that the FRC is observing. But a change in the properties of one of the objects at the other end of the relationship will not be notified to the delegate because those objects are not being observed by the FRC.

Comment: Thank you for you editting. Does any post explain this topic more detail, I couldn't find anything in apple's doc. Because you can group the fetch result use something like @"location.name", but if anything change in the `name`，things go wrong. This make a new comer surprise.

Comment: Or does any book explain this feature. I have get a book about Core Data, just show me some simple demo.